# How to efficiently sample the continuous negative binomial distribution?

Tags: random, statistics

First, for context, I am working on a game where when you do something good you earn positive credits and when you do something bad you earn negative credits, and each credit corresponds to flipping a biased coin where if you get heads then something happens (good if its a positive credit, bad if its a negative credit) and otherwise nothing happens.

The deal is that I want to handle the case of multiple credits and fractional credits, and I would like to have flips use up credits so that if something good/bad happens then the leftover credits carry over.  A straightforward way of doing this is to just perform a bunch of trials, and in particular for the case of fractional credits we can multiply the number of credits by X and the likelihood of something happening by 1/X (the distribution has the same expectation but slightly different weights);  unfortunately, this places a practical limit on how many credits the user can get and also how many decimal places can be in the number of credits since this results in an unbounded amount of work.

What I would like to do is to take advantage of the fact that I am sampling the continuous negative binomial distribution, which is the distribution of how many trials it takes to get heads, i.e. so that if f(X) is the distribution then f(X) gives the probability that there will be X tails before we run into a heads, where X need not be an integer.  If I can sample this distribution, then what I can do is that if X is the number of tails then I can see if X is greater or less than the number of credits;  if it is greater than then we use up all of the credits but nothing happens, and if it is less than or equal to then something good happens and we subtract X from the number of credits.  Furthermore, because the distribution is continuous  I can easily handle fractional credits.

Does anyone know of a way for me to be able to efficiently sample the continuous negative binomial distribution (that is, a function that generates random numbers from this distribution)?

Answer (score 2):

This question may be better answered on StatsExchange, but here I will take a stab at it.

You are correct that trying to compute this directly will be computationally expensive as you cannot avoid the beta and/or gamma function dependencies. The only statistically valid approximation I'm aware of is if the number of successes `s` required is large, and `p` is neither very small nor very large, then you can approximate it with a normal distribution with special values for the mean and variance. You can read more [here](http://www.vosesoftware.com/vosesoftware/tmp/ModelRiskHelp/Distributions/Approximating_one_distribution_with_another/Approximations_to_the_Negative_Binomial_distribution.htm) but I'm guessing this approximation will not be generally applicable for you.

The negative binomial distribution can also be approximated as a mixture of Poisson distributions, but this doesn't save you from the gamma function dependency.

The only efficient class of negative binomial samplers that I'm aware of use optimized accept-reject techniques. Pages 10-11 of this PDF [here](http://www.win.tue.nl/~marko/2WB05/lecture8.pdf) describe the concept behind the method. Page 6 (page 295 internally) of this PDF [here](http://www.aip.de/groups/soe/local/numres/bookcpdf/c7-3.pdf) contains source code for sampling binomial deviates using related techniques. Note that even these methods still require random uniform deviates as well as `sqrt()`, `log()`, and `gammln()` calls. For small numbers of trials (less than 100 maybe?) I wouldn't be surprised at all if just simulating the trials with fast random number generator is faster than even the accept-reject techniques. Definitely start by getting a fast PRNG; they are not all created equal.

**Edit:**

The following pseudo-code would probably be fairly efficient to draw a random discrete negative binomial-distributed value as long as `p` is **not** very large (too close to 1.0). It will return the number of trials required before reaching your first "desired" outcome (which is actually the first "failure" in terms of the distribution):

```
// assume p and r are the parameters to the neg. binomial dist.
// r = number of failures (you'll set to one for your purpose)
// p = probability of a "success"
double rnd = _rnd.nextDouble(); // [0.0, 1.0)
int k = 0;  // represents the # of successes that occur before 1st failure
double lastPmf = (1 - p)^r;
double cdf = lastPmf;
while (cdf < rnd)
{
    lastPmf *= (p * (k+r) / (k+1));
    cdf += lastPmf;
    k++;
}
return k;
// or return (k+1) to also count the trial on which the failure occurred
```

Using the recurrence relationship saves over repeating the factorial independently at each step. I think using this, combined with limiting your fractional precision to 1 or 2 decimal places (so you only need to multiply by 10 or 100 respectively) might work for your purposes. You are drawing only one random number and the rest is just multiplications--it should be quite fast.

Comment: Thanks for the links!  My original plan was to just simulate things directly but then I realized that if the player got 1000 credits and I allowed two decimal places then I would need to do 100,000 trials, and I'd rather not put an upper bound on the number of credits.

Comment: Thinking this over, maybe it would be better if I just put a limit on the number of decimal places and used the discrete distribution;  do you have a reference for how to sample that?

Comment: @GregoryCrosswhite Please see my edit--this method should be quite fast.

Comment: Oh, wow, that looks like just what I need!  :-D  I'll try it out.